# Eigenvalues NaN and inf

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Suppose I have a system AX =  nBX where A and B are known martrices, X is the coefficient matrix.

I am solving this using Chebyshev polynomials.

BC's are u(-1)=0=u(1)

I am imposing the bc's for the first and last rows of matrices A and B.

```
e=solve(A,B)

e[1]=0

e[-1]=0

x=solve(A,e)
```

What is wrong with this?

Comment: *What is wrong with this?* is not really much of a problem description? What inputs do you give and what outputs do they produce? What do you expect them to produce instead? Do you get exceptions? If so, include their full traceback in your question. From your [previous attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576568/eigenvalues-nan-and-inf) I conclude this is still about numpy and linear algebra, right?

Answer (score 2):

The question you seem to be asking: how come a generalized eigenvalue problem has eigenvalues inf and nan?

Your generalized eigenvalue problem is singular and has eigenvalues lambda=alpha/beta such that (alpha=0, beta=0) and (alpha!=0, beta=0). Since eigvals reports the eigenvalues, they are 0/0=nan or x/0=inf, correspondingly.

http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node35.html

If your problem shouldn't have such eigenvalues, then it's likely that there is an error in the construction of the matrices.

Comment: The problem is I think how I am imposing the boundary conditions for the two matrices. I am doing as mentioned above.